# C program to read file reading an extra line

Tags: c, file, io

The code I'm working on involves reading a file w/ input structured as the following:

```
(spaces)name(spaces) val (whatever) \n
(spaces)name(spaces) val (whatever) \n
(spaces)name(spaces) val (whatever) \n
```

Where spaces denotes an arbitrary amount of white spaces. My code is supposed to give both the name and the value. There is another condition, where everything on the line after a '#' is ignored (treated like a comment). The output is supposed be:

```
"name: (name) value: val \n"
```

For the most bit the code is working, except that it adds an extra line where it will create a set name= null and val to whatever the last number read was. For example my test file:

```
a 12
b     33
#c 15
nice 6#9
```

The output is:

```
Line after:  a 12

name: a value: 12 :
Line after: b     33 

name: b  value: 33 :
Line after:  # c 15

Line after:  nice 6#9

name: nice value: 6 :
Line after:

name:  value: 6 : //why is this happening
```

The code is here.

```
void readLine(char *filename)
{
    FILE *pf;
    char name[10000]; 
    char value[20];
    pf = fopen(filename, "r");
    char line[10000];
    if (pf){
        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), pf) != NULL) {
            //printf("Line: %s\n",line);            
                printf("Line after: %s\n",line); 
                while(true){
                    int i=0;
                    char c=line[i]; //parse every char of the line
                            //assert(c==' ');
                            int locationS=0; //index in the name
                            int locationV=0; //index in the value
                            while((c==' ')&& i<sizeof(line)){
                                //look for next sequence of chars
                                ++i;
                                c=line[i];
                                if(c=='#'){
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if(c=='#'){ break;}
                            assert(c!=' ');
                            while (c!=' '&&i<sizeof(line))
                            {
                                name[locationS]=c;
                                locationS++;
                                //printf("%d",locationS);
                                ++i;
                                c=line[i];if(c=='#'){
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if(c=='#'){ break;}
                            assert(c==' ');
                            while(c==' '&&i<sizeof(line)){
                                //look for next sequence of chars
                                ++i;
                                c=line[i];
                                if(c=='#'){
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if(c=='#'){ break;}
                            assert(c!=' ');
                            printf("\n");
                             while ((c!=' '&& c!='\n')&&i<sizeof(line))
                            {
                                value[locationV]=c;
                                locationV++;
                                ++i;
                                c=line[i];if(c=='#'){
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            printf("name: %s value: %s : \n",name, value);
                            memset(&name[0], 0, sizeof(name));
                            memset(&value[0], 0, sizeof(value));
                            break; //nothing interesting left
                }
        }
        fclose(pf);
    }else{
        printf("Error in file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using feof() in the while instead of fgets()

Comment: everything else being the same?

Comment: `i<sizeof(line)` should be `i<strlen(line)` you have other logic errors as well. (from your output, it looks like you have an extra `'\n'` at the end of your file)

Comment: @Dushara - No. The use of `fgets()` is correct.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin could you be more specific about the extra logic errors?

Comment: Sure, hold on and I'll drop an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasha, you are doing some things correctly, but then you are making what you are trying to do much more difficult that need be. First, avoid using *magic-numbers* in your code, such as `char name[10000];`. Instead:

```
...
#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char line[MAXC];
    ...
```

(you did very good following the rule *Don't skimp on Buffer Size* `:)`

Likewise you have done well in opening the file and *validating the file is open for reading* before attempting to read from it with `fgets()`. You can do that validation in a single block and handle the error at that time -- which will have the effect of reducing one-level of indention throughout the rest of your code, e.g.

```
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
```

Now with the file open and validated that it is open for reading and any error handled, you can proceed to reading each line in your file. Unless you are storing the names in an array that needs to survive your read loop, you can simply declare `name[MAXC];` within the read-loop block, e.g.

```
    while (fgets (line, MAXC, fp)) {    /* read each line of input */
        char name[MAXC];                /* storage for name */
        int val;                        /* integer value for val */
```

(**note:** rather than declare another array to hold value, we have simply declared `val` as an `int` and will use `sscanf` to parse `name` and `val` converting the value directly to `int` at that time)

Anytime you are using a *line-oriented* input function (like `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`, you will want to trim the `'\n'` read and included in the buffer that is filled. You can do that easily with the `strcspn`, see [strspn(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strspn.3.html). It is a simple, single call where you use the return from `strcspn` as the index for the `'\n'` in order to overwrite the `'\n'` with the *nul-terminating* character (which is `'\0'`, or simply `0`)

```
        line[strcspn (line, "\n")] = 0; /* trim '\n' from end of line */
```

Now all you need to do is check for the presence of the first `'#'` in `line` that marks the beginning of a comment. If found, you will simply overwrite `'#'` with the *nul-terminating* character as you did for the `'\n'`, e.g.

```
        line[strcspn (line, "#")] = 0;  /* overwrite '#' with nul-char */
```

Now that you have your line and have removed the `'\n'` and any comment that may be present, you can check that `line` isn't empty (meaning it began with a `'#'` or was simply an empty line containing only a `'\n'`)

```
        if (!*line)                     /* if empty-string */
            continue;                   /* get next line */
```

(**note:** `if (!*line)` is simply shorthand for `if (line[0] == 0)`. When you dereference your buffer, e.g. `*line` your are simply returning the first element (first char) as `*line == *(line + 0)` in pointer notation which is equivalent `*(line + 0) == line[0]` in array-index notation. The `[]` operates as a dereference as well.)

Now simply parse for the `name` and `val` directly from `line` using `sscanf`. Both the `"%s"` and `"%d"` conversion specifiers will ignore all leading whitespace before the conversion specifier. You can use this simple method so long as `name` itself does not contain whitespace. Just as you ***validate the return*** of your file opening, you will ***validate the return*** of `sscanf` to determine if the number of conversions you specified successfully took place. For example:

```
        if (sscanf (line, "%1023s %d", name, &val) == 2)  /* have name/value? */
            printf ("\nline: %s\nname: %s\nval : %d\n", line, name, val);
        else
            printf ("\nline: %s (doesn't contain name/value\n", line);
```

(**note:** by using the *field-width* modifier for your string, e.g. `"%1023s"` you protect your array-bounds for `name`. The field width limits `sscanf` from writing more than `1023 char + \0` to name. This cannot be provided by a variable or by a macro and is one of the occasions where you must stick a *magic-number* in your code... For every rule there is generally a caveat or two...)

If you asked for 2 conversions, and `sscanf` returned `2`, then you know that both the requested conversions were successful. Further, since for `val` you have specified an *integer* conversion, you are guaranteed that value will contain an *integer*.

That's all there is to it. All that remains is closing the file (if not reading from `stdin`) and you are done. A full example could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char line[MAXC];
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (line, MAXC, fp)) {    /* read each line of input */
        char name[MAXC];                /* storage for name */
        int val;                        /* integer value for val */

        line[strcspn (line, "\n")] = 0; /* trim '\n' from end of line */
        line[strcspn (line, "#")] = 0;  /* overwrite '#' with nul-char */

        if (!*line)                     /* if empty-string */
            continue;                   /* get next line */

        if (sscanf (line, "%1023s %d", name, &val) == 2)  /* have name/value? */
            printf ("\nline: %s\nname: %s\nval : %d\n", line, name, val);
        else
            printf ("\nline: %s (doesn't contain name/value\n", line);
    }
    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
}
```

(**note:** if you want to print the raw `line` before trimming the `'\n'` and comments, just move the printing of `line` before the calls to `strcspn`. Above `line` is printed showing the final state of `line` before the call to `sscanf`)

**Example Use/Output**

Using your input file stored in `dat/nameval.txt` on my system, you could simply do the following to read values redirected from `stdin`:

```
$ ./bin/parsenameval <dat/nameval.txt

line: a 12
name: a
val : 12

line: b     33
name: b
val : 33

line: nice 6
name: nice
val : 6
```

(**note:** just remove the redirection `<` to actually open and read from the file rather than having the shell do it for you. Six-to-one, half-dozen to another.)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. If for some reason you cannot use any function to help you parse the line and must use only pointers or array-indexing, let me know. Following the approach above, it takes only a little effort to replace each of the operations with its manual equivalent.